# Lazy-loading variables using overloaded decorators

Tags: python, lazy-loading, decorator

I have a state object that represents a system. Properties within the state object are populated from [huge] text files. As not every property is accessed every time a state instance, is created, it makes sense to lazily load them.:

```
class State:
    def import_positions(self):
        self._positions = {}
        # Code which populates self._positions

    @property
    def positions(self):
        try:
            return self._positions
        except AttributeError:
            self.import_positions()
            return self._positions

    def import_forces(self):
        self._forces = {}
        # Code which populates self._forces

    @property
    def forces(self):
        try:
            return self._forces
        except AttributeError:
            self.import_forces()
            return self._forces
```

There's a lot of repetitive boilerplate code here. Moreover, sometimes an import_abc can populate a few variables (i.e. import a few variables from a small data file if its already open).

It makes sense to overload @property such that it accepts a function to "provide" that variable, viz:

```
class State:
    def import_positions(self):
        self._positions = {}
        # Code which populates self._positions

    @lazyproperty(import_positions)
    def positions(self):
        pass

    def import_forces(self):
        self._forces = {}
        # Code which populates self._forces and self._strain

    @lazyproperty(import_forces)
    def forces(self):
        pass

    @lazyproperty(import_forces)
    def strain(self):
        pass
```

However, I cannot seem to find a way to trace exactly what **method** are being called in the @property decorator. As such, I don't know how to approach overloading @property into my own @lazyproperty.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want something like this. It's a sort of simple memoization function combined with `@property`.

```
def lazyproperty(func):
    values = {}
    def wrapper(self):
        if not self in values:
            values[self] = func(self)
        return values[self]
    wrapper.__name__ = func.__name__
    return property(wrapper)

class State:
    @lazyproperty
    def positions(self):
        print 'loading positions'
        return {1, 2, 3}

s = State()
print s.positions
print s.positions
```

Which prints:

```
loading positions
set([1, 2, 3])
set([1, 2, 3])
```

Caveat: entries in the values dictionary won't be garbage collected, so it's not suitable for long-running programs. If the loaded value is immutable across all classes, it can be stored on the function object itself for better speed and memory use:

```
try:
    return func.value
except AttributeError:
    func.value = func(self)
    return func.value
```

Comment: This will not work if you create more than one instance of `State`.  You're storing the data on the function object of the method, but the method only exists once at the class level, so whatever you do to it will affect all instances.  If you make a second `State` and mutate its positions, you'll see the changes show up in both instances.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can remove even more boilerplate by writing a custom descriptor class that decorates the loader method.  The idea is to have the descriptor itself encode the lazy-loading logic, meaning that the only thing you define in an actual method is the loader itself (which is the only thing that, apparently, really does have to vary for different values).  Here's an example:

```
class LazyDesc(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.loader = func
        self.secretAttr = '_' + func.__name__

    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        try:
            return getattr(obj, self.secretAttr)
        except AttributeError:
            print("Lazily loading", self.secretAttr)
            self.loader(obj)
            return getattr(obj, self.secretAttr)

class State(object):
    @LazyDesc
    def positions(self):
        self._positions = {'some': 'positions'}

    @LazyDesc
    def forces(self):
        self._forces = {'some': 'forces'}
```

Then:

```
>>> x = State()
>>> x.forces
Lazily loading _forces
{'some': 'forces'}
>>> x.forces
{'some': 'forces'}
>>> x.positions
Lazily loading _positions
{'some': 'positions'}
>>> x.positions
{'some': 'positions'}
```

Notice that the "lazy loading" message was printed only on the first access for each attribute.  This version also auto-creates the "secret" attribute to hold the real data by prepending an underscore to the method name (i.e., data for `positions` is stored in `_positions`.  In this example, there's no setter, so you can't do `x.positions = blah` (although you can still mutate the positions with `x.positions['key'] = val`), but the approach could be extended to allow setting as well.

The nice thing about this approach is that your lazy logic is transparently encoded in the descriptor `__get__`, meaning that it easily generalizes to other kinds of boilerplate that you might want to abstract away in a similar manner.

Answer (score 1):

> However, I cannot seem to find a way to trace exactly what method are
>   being called in the @property decorator.

`property` is actually a type (whether you use it with the decorator syntax of not is orthogonal), which implements the `descriptor protocol` (https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html). An overly simplified (I skipped the deleter, doc and quite a few other things...) pure-python implementation would look like this:

```
class property(object):
    def __init__(self, fget=None, fset=None):
        self.fget = fget
        self.fset = fset

    def setter(self, func):
        self.fset = func
        return func

    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        return self.fget(obj)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if self.fset:
            self.fset(obj, value)
        else:
            raise AttributeError("Attribute is read-only")
```

Now overloading `property` is not necessarily the simplest solution. In fact there are actually quite a couple existing implementations out there, including Django's "cached_property" (cf http://ericplumb.com/blog/understanding-djangos-cached_property-decorator.html for more about it) and pydanny's "cached-property" package (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cached-property/0.1.5)